# Bash sort files by filename containing year and abbreviated month

Tags: linux, bash, sorting

I have files for many years and all months, with example names: `dir1/dir2/dir3/file_name_2017_v_2017.Jan.exp.var.txt`, `dir1/dir2/dir3/file_name_2017_v_2017.Feb.exp.var.txt`, …, and `dir1/dir2/dir3/file_name_2017_v_2017.Dec.exp.var.txt`.

There is a script executing a one line command to store a list of files in an array.

```
ls dir1/dir2/dir3/file_name_2017_v_*.exp.var.txt
```

This works, however they are out of order by month.  I would like them to be sorted by YYYY.MMM.  I have tried various sort commands using -M to lastly sort by month, however nothing is working.  What am I missing to sort these files?  I prefer a one-line command to sort these.

Edit 1:
Using ls *.txt | sort --field-separator='.' -k 1,2M -r reverses the year order, and the alphabetical order of the months.  Removing the -r puts the years in chronological order, however the months are in alphabetical order.  This is not what I want, as I want the files in chronological order

Comment: you are missing the sort --field-separator switch.`sort --field-separator='.' -k 1,2` along this line.

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't working - the months are still not in order.

Comment: Time to rename the files with a script i think...

Comment: These files do have the same year, however other directories have years that are different before and after the _v_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this command:

`ls dir1/dir2/dir3/file_name_2017_v_*.exp.var.txt | sort -t '.' -k 1.33,1.36n -k 2,2M`

Or use `_` as the field-separator:

`ls dir1/dir2/dir3/file_name_2017_v_*.exp.var.txt | sort -t '_' -k 5.1,5.4n -k 5.6,5.8M`

If years that are different before and after the `v`, need to add another `-k`:

`ls dir1/dir2/dir3/file_name_*_v_*.exp.var.txt | sort -t '_' -k 3.1,3.4n -k 5.1,5.4n -k 5.6,5.8M`

Example(Update):

```
$ mkdir -p dir1/dir2/dir3
$ touch dir1/dir2/dir3/file_name_2017_v_201{5..7}.{Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec}.exp.var.txt
$ ls dir1/dir2/dir3/file_name_2017_v_*.exp.var.txt | sort -t '.' -k 1.33,1.36n -k 2,2M
$ ls dir1/dir2/dir3/file_name_2017_v_*.exp.var.txt | sort -t '_' -k 5.1,5.4n -k 5.6,5.8M
dir1/dir2/dir3/file_name_2017_v_2015.Jan.exp.var.txt
dir1/dir2/dir3/file_name_2017_v_2015.Feb.exp.var.txt
dir1/dir2/dir3/file_name_2017_v_2015.Mar.exp.var.txt
dir1/dir2/dir3/file_name_2017_v_2015.Apr.exp.var.txt
dir1/dir2/dir3/file_name_2017_v_2015.May.exp.var.txt
dir1/dir2/dir3/file_name_2017_v_2015.Jun.exp.var.txt
dir1/dir2/dir3/file_name_2017_v_2015.Jul.exp.var.txt
dir1/dir2/dir3/file_name_2017_v_2015.Aug.exp.var.txt
dir1/dir2/dir3/file_name_2017_v_2015.Sep.exp.var.txt
dir1/dir2/dir3/file_name_2017_v_2015.Oct.exp.var.txt
dir1/dir2/dir3/file_name_2017_v_2015.Nov.exp.var.txt
dir1/dir2/dir3/file_name_2017_v_2015.Dec.exp.var.txt
dir1/dir2/dir3/file_name_2017_v_2016.Jan.exp.var.txt
dir1/dir2/dir3/file_name_2017_v_2016.Feb.exp.var.txt
dir1/dir2/dir3/file_name_2017_v_2016.Mar.exp.var.txt
dir1/dir2/dir3/file_name_2017_v_2016.Apr.exp.var.txt
dir1/dir2/dir3/file_name_2017_v_2016.May.exp.var.txt
dir1/dir2/dir3/file_name_2017_v_2016.Jun.exp.var.txt
dir1/dir2/dir3/file_name_2017_v_2016.Jul.exp.var.txt
dir1/dir2/dir3/file_name_2017_v_2016.Aug.exp.var.txt
dir1/dir2/dir3/file_name_2017_v_2016.Sep.exp.var.txt
dir1/dir2/dir3/file_name_2017_v_2016.Oct.exp.var.txt
dir1/dir2/dir3/file_name_2017_v_2016.Nov.exp.var.txt
dir1/dir2/dir3/file_name_2017_v_2016.Dec.exp.var.txt
dir1/dir2/dir3/file_name_2017_v_2017.Jan.exp.var.txt
dir1/dir2/dir3/file_name_2017_v_2017.Feb.exp.var.txt
dir1/dir2/dir3/file_name_2017_v_2017.Mar.exp.var.txt
dir1/dir2/dir3/file_name_2017_v_2017.Apr.exp.var.txt
dir1/dir2/dir3/file_name_2017_v_2017.May.exp.var.txt
dir1/dir2/dir3/file_name_2017_v_2017.Jun.exp.var.txt
dir1/dir2/dir3/file_name_2017_v_2017.Jul.exp.var.txt
dir1/dir2/dir3/file_name_2017_v_2017.Aug.exp.var.txt
dir1/dir2/dir3/file_name_2017_v_2017.Sep.exp.var.txt
dir1/dir2/dir3/file_name_2017_v_2017.Oct.exp.var.txt
dir1/dir2/dir3/file_name_2017_v_2017.Nov.exp.var.txt
dir1/dir2/dir3/file_name_2017_v_2017.Dec.exp.var.txt
```

P.S. You need to count the start and end index of the month, e.g. its `1.33,1.36n` in your example.

Comment: Interesting, works only on fixed length names though.

Comment: if filename doesn't contain underline，can use `_` as the field-separator: `ls dir1/dir2/dir3/file_name_2017_v_*.exp.var.txt | sort -t '_' -k 5.1,5.4n -k 5.6,6.8M`

Comment: I couldn't get your first example to work the way I needed it, as it was ordering by all Jan years, Feb years, Mar years, …, Nov years, and Dec years.  Your second example using sort -t '_' -k 5.1,5.4n -k 5.6,6.8M works perfectly.

Comment: Both the commands should be the same. They sort by the year number first, and then by month if the year is the same.